# ¿Como Cambiar en Python Pandas el tipo de dato a numerico en una o varias columnas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Utilizando Python 3.4 y pandas = 0.19.2, realice un script en el cual cambio el tipo de datos a una columna de datos del dataFrame. Utilizando esta version de pandas tenía una línea de código con

```
pd.lib.infer_dtype
```

En mi anterior pregunta me recomendaron actualizar la versión de pandas y cambiar la instruccion por:

```
prod.apply(lambda x: pd.api.types.infer_dtype(x.values)).
```

Sin embargo, al cambiar la versión de Python a la más reciente y la versión de pandas a la 0.22 comenzaron a surgir varios problemas con mi código entre ellos:

Al importar la libreria datetime de la siguiente forma:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Mi Widget Calendar de PyQt5 se cierra inesperadamente al dar click en una fecha

y otro error es que al querer cambiar el formato de una columna de celdas a numeric simplemente ignora estas líneas de código y ya no responde.

```
lista1 = lista1.rename(columns = {'indice_planta':'planta','producto1':'producto', 'cajas_prod1': 'cajas','lbs_prod1': 'lbs', 'vel_producto1': 'velocidad', 'tprod1': 'tipo', 'resto1':'resto' })
lista1[['cajas','velocidad','lbs']] = lista1[['cajas','velocidad','lbs']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

(en la anterior version de Python y Pandas no tenía este problema)

Otra cosa que he notado es que la consola ya no me muestra los errores que se van presentando, solamente ya no hace nada

tengo el script completo en GitHub en el siguiente link:

https://github.com/alexogch1/Analisis_Embolsados y el archivo es /analisis_prod.py

Ojalá me puedan ayudar a decirme que tengo que hacer para evitar estos problemas, el cambio de versión me ha complicado las cosas.

Comment: Un problema que encontre fue en la instruccion: `lista1[['cajas','velocidad','lbs']] = lista1[['cajas','velocidad','lbs']].apply(pd.to_numeric)`, el problema es causado porque estas tratando de convertir string del tipo '1,566' con comas, que no son soportados para una conversion directa ya que deben ser puntos. la solucion fue reemplazar la coma por punto usando lo siguiente: `lista1[['cajas','velocidad','lbs']] = lista1[['cajas','velocidad','lbs']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.astype(str).str.replace(',','.')))`

Comment: Otro error fue en `inicio = fecha_1
        fin    = fecha_2`, fecha_1 y fecha_2 no existen en ese contexto, debes usar lo siguiente: `inicio = self.fecha_1
        fin    = self.fecha_2`.

Comment: Te recomiendo que ejecutes tu aplicacion desde la consola ya que los mensajes de error son impresos claramente, si usas alguna IDE estos a veces no muestran el mensaje de error de forma correcta.

Comment: gracias. no puedo calificar tu comentario porque no lo pusiste como respuesta.